# Trigger Email for Azure AD Failed Logons

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am familiar with ADD sign-ins under Monitoring and under Users. I see the PowerShell commandlets in Preview. This is not what will give a solution. I thought this would be an easy task and easily found on the internet but after hours and hours of searching, nothing that I believe will satisfy the simple request below.

Fairly small company so not too concerned on the amount of emails. I am looking on how to script a program (I am a novice but willing to learn) to receive an email anytime a failed sign-in occurs.  Has anyone done this for Azure AD before or know how to do it?

Thank you ahead of time.
stevelsd

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write a program to do this.

It is standard functionality in Activity policies. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/user-activity-policies for details.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am going to test this out this evening.  I will report tomorrow.

Comment: This might be a "standard functionality" but from what I can see it might have been overlooked to see it is part of an additional paid package; "Microsoft Cloud App Security" which also includes the requirement for premium licenses?  Is this not true.  Also, to do what I was looking for (even though i have a P1 license), it also appears this standard functionality is not part of the "Discovery" functions allowed in P1 which then means additional license costs.  Am I correct or am I mistaken?  Than ks.